# Using Google VR in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr

I am using the latest google vr plugin for unity and latest unity version but it seems that the split screen and the head movement doesn't work?

I have read some of article that if you build it will automatically show in the mobile device but in my case it doesn't any advice on this one?

Here are my settings in unity. Thanks in advance

[image: my settings]

Comment: I think we need some more information: did you use the demo-scene from GVR plugin? I can see a MainCamera in your scene?! Open the `Assets/GoogleVR/Demos/Scenes/HelloVR.unity` scene. Open the build settings and add this scene to the `scenes to build`. Usually there is no `MainCamera` in scene, just an `GVR` object. Within this object you can set the settings for split-screen and so on

Comment: about that too, the hellovr.unity dosnt work to in my mobile. and theres actually a `Main Camera` under `player` object. where can i find the split-screen settings? thnks for replying btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make an answer because a comment would be too long:

If the HelloVR.unity scene is not working on your mobile-phone, your phone might be not supported? Is it running in Editor?

In the Editor you can not see split screen. But you can use `Instant Preview` - [here you can find a documentation.](https://developers.google.com/vr/develop/unity/instant-preview) I think that is the best way to check if split screen is working.

In your scene you have to find `GvrEventSystem`: here you can enable `VR Mode Only`: your app will always render in split-screen on mobile. (But not in Editor mode!) If this is not check you can switch between 2D and split-screen via VR settings.

How I made it run:

1. Clone GVR repo [from here](https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-unity-sdk.git)
2. Open downloaded repo with Unity
3. In your BuildSettings switch to `Android` and check `Development Build`
4. Open HelloVR.unity scene
5. enable `VR Mode Only` in `GvrEventSystem`
6. Under `DemoInputManager` I set `GVR Emulated Platform Type` to `Cardboard`
7. Under `GvrControllerMain` set `Emulator Connection Mode` to `USB`
8. [Enable developer options on your phone](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options)
9. Connect your phone and check connection via `AndroidStudio` or `Android Device Manager` - if your phone is not listed here, something went wrong and you have to install additional drivers for your phone
10. Hit run: screen should be displayed in split-screen mode on your phone

And again: if your phone displays the scene, but no splitscreen or gyro movement is detected your phone is probably not supported. You can check for errors using the `Android Device Manager`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem once , the phone I was testing did not have a gyroscope included. Try to get a phone with gyroscope included.

Comment: yeah me to but it works now, i had to test it to another device